# In React useEffect shoud l I return an inline function that calls another function or just the function itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect

Basically my question is whether there is any runtime difference between the two ways I list below of returning a cleanup function from a useEffect call. Is there a common best practice? I didn't see anything about it in the reactjs docs so I'm curious if there is any advantage to either practice.

Specifically:

- Is the call stack different aside from the extra anonymous function?
- Are there circumstances where it might affect the *this* keyword?
- Is one safer than the other?

---

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function aPlainJsFunction() {
    console.log("Bar");
}

Example = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Foo");
        return aPlainJsFunction; // **This Line**
    }
    return <Text>Example</Text>
}
```

-or-

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function aPlainJsFunction() {
    console.log("Bar");
}

Example = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Foo");
        return () => aPlainJsFunction(); // **This line**
    }
    return <Text>Example</Text>
}
```

Comment: `this` isn't used inside the `() => ...`, so no that cannot matter.

Comment: Well no  not in the example, but say it were used

Answer (score 1):

> Is the call stack different aside from the extra anonymous function?

No

> Are there circumstances where it might affect the this keyword?

No

> Is one safer than the other?

No

Comment: it's a hard no on the second question, at least with the example provided